# Finding out with wxWidgets: Is this a writeable directory?

Tags: directory, wxwidgets

I have a `wxFilenName mydir` that *should* point to a writeable directory. Ultimately, `mydir` has been obtained via `mydir=otherfilename.GetPath()` (though via some disgressions maybe). Assuming that `mydir`refers to (on a Windows box) `C:\foo\bar`, I need to ensure that `C:\foo\bar`exists and is a directory (not a file) and I have write permissions (so I might create `C:\foo\bar\baz`).
What I do is to check `mydir.IsOk() && mydir.DirExists() && mydir.IsDirWriteable()`, but I suspect this does not do what I want. From reading the wxwidgets docs, I gather that it *does* distinguish between a `wxFileName` referencing `C:\foo\bar`in the sense of "the file/dir `bar` in the directory `C:\foo`" versus `C:\foo\bar` in the sense of "the directoy `C:\foo\bar` and no particular file in it") so that I'd expect my method to work as `GetPath()`should return such a "pure" directory. However, I suspect (and testing indicates) that my checks really check if `C:\foo` is a writeable directory ...

What would be a better method (within the wxWidgets framework)? Do I really need to append some dummy filename before performing my checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [wxFileName::DirName()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_name.html#afed95ad83636ed634bbe09564457bfe2) to create an object representing a directory.